# How to make a transition from one fragment to another?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have recyclerView class. There are information that I have to display in fragments. For example: recyclerView contains : id, name, surname. The rirst fragment contains name, I click name and will be shown the second fragment with another data. It works ok but the one problem: when should shown the first fragment - there are 2 fragments. and when after clicking should be the second fragment - there are 2 fragments too. my problem is that I can't do that the first fragment was hidden. Please, help me. Thank you.

activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="com.company.androidretrofit.NameFragment"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/name_fragment"/>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:name="com.company.androidretrofit.NewsFragment"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/details_fragment">
    </fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    }
}
```

first fragment:

```
public class NameFragment extends Fragment implements OnTextClickListener, Callback<News> {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private NewsAdapter newsAdapter;
    private RestClient restClient = new RestClient();

    public NameFragment() {
    }

    
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.name_fragment, container, false);
        restClient.startRetrofit();
        loadJSON();
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext()));
        return view;

    }
    private void loadJSON() {
        final Call<News> news = restClient.getApiInterface().getNews();
        news.enqueue(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onTextClick(String title) {

        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getContext();
        String sourceIdItem = title;
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("sourceId", sourceIdItem);

        NewsFragment newsFragment = new NewsFragment();
        newsFragment.setArguments(bundle);

        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment2, newsFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Got: " + title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<News> call, Response<News> response) {
        List<Source> sources = response.body().getSources();

        newsAdapter = new NewsAdapter(getActivity(), sources, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<News> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.d("error", "can't parse data: ", t);
    }
}
```

second fragment:

```
public class NewsFragment extends Fragment {
    private String sourceId;

    public NewsFragment() {
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_fragment, container, false);
        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.sourceIdItem);
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
       sourceId = bundle.getString("sourceId");
          textView.setText(sourceId);
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you describe what you want to achieve in more detail? I don't understand the phrasing

Comment: You cannot use `replace` with a `<fragment>` tag. Consider switching to `<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>`, which doesn't suffer from that same problem.

Comment: I changed <fragment> to <FrameLayout> - but nothing changed.